# Polynomials $P(x)$ satisfying $P(2x-x^2) = (P(x))^2$

Tags: polynomials, functional-equations

I am looking (to answer a question [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=Xw5T-a-CaUkC&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=%22find+all+functions%22+%22continuous+at+at+least+one+point+in%22&source=bl&ots=iXrYRLY9eN&sig=rPWgv3f3tv_sn3_bBm4WQuO8844&hl=en&ei=gmXPTKufOcT38Ab-4OzAAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CBcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22find%20all%20functions%22%20%22continuous%20at%20at%20least%20one%20point%20in%22&f=false)) for all polynomials $P(x)$ satisfying the functional equation given in the title.

It is not hard to notice (given that one instinctively wants to complete the square in $P(2x - x^2)$ ) that $P(x) = 1-x$ is a solution; and the product relation

$$P(2x-x^2) = P(x)^2, Q(2x-x^2) = Q(x)^2 \implies (P\cdot Q)(2x-x^2) = (P\cdot Q)(x)^2 $$

shows that $(1-x)^n$ are all solutions as well.

Apart from the constant solutions $0$ and $1$, is it true that $(1-x)^n$ are all solutions? Could somebody give me a hint as to how to prove this (or a counterexample)?

**Edit:** I haven't had luck finding a formula for the $n$th derivatives of $P(x)$ at one in the case $P(1) = 1$, though the first two are zero.

Comment: Hint: Binomial Theorem.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get that hint @HowardRoark.

Comment: I just looked at it an thought, maybe you can expand both sides using the binomial Theorem. Then see if the sides are equal.

Comment: We have $P^2(1)=P(1)$ so $P(1)=0$ or $P(1)=1$. If $P(1)=0$, let $Q(x)=\frac{P(x)}{1-x}$. Easy calculation shows $Q$ satisfies the same functional equation. Repeat. But we must deal with $P(1)=1$. Repeated differentiation shows that $P'(1)=0$, $P''(1)=0$, and so on. I am pretty sure this takes care of things but have not written out details.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I was just doing the same calculation!

Comment: @AndréNicolas I wasn't able to show that $P^{(n)}(1) = 0$ for all orders $n$; but what about the fact that $1 = P(1) = P(P(1)) = ...$ in case $P(1) = 1$?

Comment: This does not appear to be directly useful, since it carries no more information than $P(1)=1$. Busy for quite a while, will write it up later if not answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The polynomial $Q(x)=P(1-x)$ solves $Q(x)^2=Q(x^2)$. Every $Q(x)=x^n$ is solution, as well as $Q(x)=0$. For every positive integer $k$, let us denote by $o(k)$ every polynomial of degree at most $k-1$.

- If $Q(x)=ax^n+o(n)$ with $a\ne0$ then $Q(x)^2=a^2x^{2n}+o(2n)$ while $Q(x^2)=ax^{2n}+o(2n)$ hence $a=1$.
- If $Q(x)=x^n+ax^m+o(m)$ with $m\lt n$ then $Q(x)^2=x^{2n}+2ax^{n+m}+o(n+m)$ while $Q(x^2)=x^{2n}+ax^{2m}+o(2m)$ hence $a=0$.

Finally the solutions are the polynomials $P(x)=0$, $P(x)=1$ and $P(x)=(1-x)^n$ with $n\geqslant1$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm confused about your first line. I'm assuming that you meant, given $P$ satisfying $P(2y - y^2) = P(y)^2$, that setting $y = 1-x$ always yields $P(x)^2 = P(x^2)$. However, when I do this, I come out with $P(-x^2) = P(1-x)^2$. What am I missing?

Comment: Okay, hold on, I think I get it! If we fix $x$, take the original functional equation $P(2y - y^2) = P(y)^2$, and put $y = 1-x$, we come out with $P(1-x^2) = P(1-x)^2$. Thus, for every $x$, your function $Q(x)$ has your stated property.

Comment: The equation to be solved is $P(1-(1-x)^2)=P(x)^2$ or $P(C(S(C(x))=S(P(x))$ where $S(x)=x^2$ and $C(x)=1-x$. Composing with $C$ (note $C^2=1$) this is $PCS=SPC$ so that squaring commutes with $PC$, i.e., with $P(1-x)$.

Comment: @zyx It's okay, I just saw how $Q(x^2) = Q(x)^2$ whenever $Q(x)$ is $P(1-x)$ for $P(x)$ satisfying the functional equation.

Comment: Did, could you give a bit more justification for your second paragraph (that $a=1$)?

Comment: Given $P$ such that $P(2y-y^2)=P(y)^2$ and defining $Q(x)=P(1-x)$, one gets $Q(x^2)=P(1-x^2)=P(2(1-x)-(1-x)^2)=P(1-x)^2=Q(x)^2$. (This addresses @user's first comment.)

Comment: About @user's second question: if $Q(x)^2=Q(x^2)$, the leading terms $a^2x^{2n}$ and $ax^{2n}$ coincide, hence $a=a^2$. Since $a\ne0$, $a=1$.

Comment: Oh yeah... sorry, my bad.

Comment: To briefly recapitulate your proof (to check my understanding): first, you showed that $Q(x) = P(1-x)$ always satisfies $Q(x)^2 = Q(x^2)$. Then, you showed that the only functions $Q(x)$ must be $0, 1$, or $x^n$. Then, since $P(1-x) = x^n$ or $0$, $P(x) = P(1-(1-x)) = (1-x)^n$ or $0$.

Comment: That's it, except that your last $P(1-x)=x^n$ should read $Q(1-x)=x^n$.

Comment: How did you think of this??? I get that one might try shifting a proof $P(x) = (1-x)^n$ to a proof $P(1-x) = x^n$, but after that...?

Comment: @user1296727, our comments crossed in editing.  The unstated fact that should be mentioned is that possibilities for $P(F(x))=F(P(x))$ for polynomials are extremely limited, so once it is recognized that your equation fits that pattern, the problem is in some sense "done" (or one can quote the classification of solutions).  Another is that if you see from the beginning that there is a family of solutions to $P(f(x))=g(P(x))$ it is likely that it comes from a family of commuting polynomials.

Comment: A strong hint is in $2x-x^2$ being "almost" a square then the idea that Square(P)=P(square) or something similar is in the air.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s an answer that has the same content as @Did‘s, but organized differently:

Let $f(x)=2x-x^2$ and also let $u(x)=1-x$, thought of as a transformation of the (real) line. Let $g=u^{-1}\circ f\circ u$, which you compute to be $g(x)=x^2$. Now let $Q=P\circ u$, so that $P=Q\circ u^{-1}$ and the requirement $P^2=P\circ f$ gets translated to $(Q\circ u^{-1})^2=Q\circ u^{-1}\circ u\circ g\circ u^{-1}=Q\circ g\circ u^{-1}$. This is requiring $g\circ Q\circ u^{-1}=Q\circ g\circ u^{-1}$, in other words $g\circ Q=Q\circ g$. We’re asking which polynomials commute with $x^2$ in the sense of substitution. But the only such polynomials are the pure monomials $Q=x^n$ (and the constant zero, of course). Resubstitute and get @Did’s result.

Comment: By the way, do you happen to know if the classification of commuting polynomials has been completed in characteristic $p$?